# Django check if url parameter was provided

Tags: django, url, get, django-urls

i have a url :

```
path('admin-panel/users/update/<id>/',user_update_for_admin, name="user_update_for_admin"),
```

and the view for that url:

```
def user_update_for_admin(request,id):

    user = get_object_or_404(UsersForAdmin, id=id)
```

everything works fine but  if an id is not provided in the url  for exemple  if i type :

admin-panel/users/update/

i got this error:
**Field 'id' expected a number but got 'update'.**
how do i fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [*path converter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) such that the URL will only "fire" in case it is an number (sequence of digits):

```
path(
    'admin-panel/users/update/<int:id>/',
    user_update_for_admin,
    name='user_update_for_admin'
),
```

In case you pass a non-int value, it will not "fire" and look for other paths. If no paths capture the url pattern, it will return a 404, which is probably the most sensical HTTP response.

You furthermore need to rewrite the path above to:

```
path(
    'admin-panel/users/<int:id>/',
    user_detail_for_admin,
    name='user_detail_for_admin'
)
```

Comment: @NAS: is something else referring to the `user_update_for_admin` function? You did use `<int:...>`, right?

Comment: @NAS: at first sight it looks like you also have a path `admin-panel/users/<id>` (so where `update` matches with `id`).

Comment: :no  only one path is referring to that  view and yes i used <int:id> but i did  extend the user model is that a problem ??

Comment: @NAS: normally not. Are you sure the error is raised by the same view?

Comment: @NAS: normally the path `admin-panel/users/update/` however should not trigger this view in the first place, since it requires at least one character for `<id>`.

Comment: i will  post  all my url paths  please look the  answer down bellow

Comment: @NAS: the path one line above it is the culprit, this needs an `<int:...>` as well. In fact, probably most (all) `<id>`s are better replaced by `<int:id>`.

Comment: thank you very much   it works , after i've added <int:id> to all paths